# Can an entry in Esri GeoPortal Server contain both ArcGIS Server and *.zip links?

Tags: esri-geoportal-server

Does anyone know whether a dataset in [Esri GeoPortal Server](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/geoportal) can support both Preview (in ArcGIS Server), and Download (of a zip file) on the same dataset?

Eg [this dataset](http://gptogc.esri.com/geoportal/catalog/search/resource/details.page?uuid=%7BEBBDDD03-13B6-4086-B653-47B942765651%7D) has a link to Preview in ArcGIS Server. Could this same dataset also contain a Download option, which linked to a zip file? If so, how would that be set up?

[image]

(*Open* takes you to the REST endpoint. *Preview, KML, NMF* and *LYR* are auto-generated by ArcGIS Server. Can I also include a Zip file of related data, which I would create manually?)